# How do I retrieve only the snippet of text from a user thread through the gmail api?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, gmail-api

I am trying to retrieve as much text as I can from the users emails from the gmail api. I have successfully retrieved the thread list id, the thread id, the history id, and a snippet of text from the thread aka email. What Im trying to accomplish to only retrieve a snippet of text from the thread or email, or possibly all the text from the thread of email. Here is my code so far and the restults I

```
- (void)fetchThreads{

 self.output.text = @"\n Getting threads...";
//     NSString *threadID = @"15fb742b462acbdc";
//     NSString *threadID1 = @"15f56dc58e92f914";
//     NSString *messageID = @"0x600000453020";

     GTLRGmailQuery_UsersThreadsList *query = [GTLRGmailQuery_UsersThreadsList queryWithUserId:@"me"];


     query.q = @"in:drafts";
     query.userId = @"me";


 self.service.shouldFetchNextPages = true;
    NSLog(@"The number is 1");
 [self.service executeQuery:query

 delegate:self

 didFinishSelector:@selector(displayResultWithTicket2:finishedWithObject:error:)];

 }




- (void)displayResultWithTicket2:(GTLRServiceTicket *)ticket finishedWithObject:(GTLRGmail_ListThreadsResponse *)threadResponse
                           error:(NSError *)error {

    if (error == nil) {

        NSMutableString *threadString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

        if (threadResponse.threads.count > 0) {

            [threadString appendString:@"Labels:\n"];

            for (GTLRGmail_Thread *thread in threadResponse.threads) {
                [threadString appendFormat:@"\n This is message %@ \n", thread];

            }

        } else {

            [threadString appendString:@"No labels found."];
            NSLog(@"The eror is %@", error.localizedDescription);
        }

        self.output.text = threadString;

    } else {

        [self showAlert:@"Error" message:error.localizedDescription];

    }

}
```

Results:

```
This is message GTLRGmail_Thread 0x604000259200: {id:"15f500862dbcee7b" snippet:"Coffin of Ankhefenmut Author: John Smith Professor: Ms. Strum Course: Survey of Art in the Western World I, ARH170 Due Date: 10/24/17 The Ancient Egyptians are one of the worlds oldest civilizations" historyId:"2636014"} 

 This is message GTLRGmail_Thread 0x604000259470: {id:"15f02e206c54b910" snippet:"A Review of Alice Goffman&#39;s “On the Run” Alice Goffman&#39;s “On the Run” is a well-conducted sociological and ethnographical incite into the lives of young black youth during the “Tough on Crime”" historyId:"2636016"} 

 This is message GTLRGmail_Thread 0x60400024ec70: {id:"15ec4d1581e8bf30" snippet:" Introduction to Social Research - Ms. Wynn | Due 9/28/17 | 001261311 The Tearoom Trade Study Review The sociologist Laud Humphrey&#39;s conducted a very controversial study in the" historyId:"2406852"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to implement this on Objective-C. Using the [Users.messages.get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get), just place the "snippet" property as 'fields' parameter. This will return the snippet response only.

A sample response from the [Try-it](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get#try-it) applying that:

```
{
 "snippet": "Your script, testscript, has recently failed to finish successfully."
}
```